# R - Order each matrix inside a list of matrices

Tags: r

I have a list where each element is a matrix, and I want to order each matrix individually

Order a matrix is as easy as this:

```
data <- data[order(data$value),]
```

But I am struggling to order a list of matrix individually

I have tried this with  some variations:

```
 for(i in 1:lenght(data)){
 data[i] <- data[i][order(data[i]$value),]
 }
```

data is the list that contains matrices

I have also tried with apply functions

Some ideas?

Thanks!!

All the code:

```
#The aim is to show one hospital for each state given an outcome 
#in the posotion num of the ranking, its a learning exercise

rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best"){

if (outcome == "heart attack"){
  col <- 11
}else if(outcome == "heart failure"){
  col <- 17
}else if(outcome == "pneumonia"){
  col <- 23
}else{
  stop("invalid outcome")
}

data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

data <- data[, c(2, 7,col)]

colnames(data) <- c("Hospital", "State", "value")
data$value <- as.numeric(data$value)
data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
data <- split(data, data$State)

#data2 is the final result dataframe
data2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 3))
colnames(data2) <- c("Hospital", "State", "value")

#From here is what I do not know how to do it.

#data is a list of matrices, each matrix corresponds to a state
#data2 is the result dataframe, where I am going to add the row num of each 
matrix in data

#1. Order each matrix in data by value and alfabetically if tie
#2. Add to data 2 the row num of each matrix in data once they are sort

for(i in 1:lenght(data)){

data[i] <- data[i][order(data[i]$Hospital),]
data[i] <- data[i][order(data[i]$value),]

if(num =="best"){
  num = 1;
}else if(num == "worst"){
  num = nrow(data[i])
}

num <- as.numeric(num)

rbind(data2,data[i][num])

}

return(data2)

}
```

Sorry about identations, it changed when I paste the code

Comment: What is the output of your code? An error or incorrect results? - perhaps try breaking it down further by adding the sorted matrices into a new list, instead of overwriting the matrix you just sorted.

Comment: The code that I post it is only for know what I want to do. Because lenght(data) give me an error saying that could not find a function"lenght" and if I change that to 1:4 only for test purposes it gives me an error saying in the function order the argument is not a vector but when I do it with an unquie matrix its work perfect. The problem is that I think I do not know how to work with a list of matrices

Comment: But what is the problem? What have you actually tried? If we know the concrete problem/error, a better answer can be given. Given what you say and your code examples, I don't know what the problem is, because it looks like it would work.

Comment: There you have the code. I think my approach to this kind of problem is bad and I do not know how to reference and treat matrices inside a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I did not have your exact data (I don't have the csv file), I created a dummy dataframe ([swiped from this tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-sorting-a-data-frame-by-the-contents-of-a-column/)):

```
numPeople = 10
sex=sample(c("male","female"),numPeople,replace=T)
age = sample(14:102, numPeople, replace=T)
income = sample(20:150, numPeople, replace=T)
minor = age<18

population = data.frame(sex=sex, age=age, income=income, minor=minor)
population

> population
      sex age income minor
1    male  34    130 FALSE
2    male  48     86 FALSE
3  female 101     36 FALSE
4    male  64     78 FALSE
5  female  97     92 FALSE
6    male  19     45 FALSE
7  female  42    124 FALSE
8  female  24     68 FALSE
9  female  24     96 FALSE
10 female  91     30 FALSE
```

This means you will have to adjust the variable names and so on to match your example, but can learn how to order a list of matrices. More specifically, you really have a list of `data.frame` objects, after using the `split` function. it is important to notice the difference between a data.frame and a matrix, as they can behave differently.

I will split the `data.frame` by the `sex` column:

```
l = split(population, population$sex)
```

You can test that each element of the resulting list is indeed a `data.frame` (and not a matrix) by running:

```
> is.data.frame(l[[1]])
[1] TRUE
```

Notice that you have to use the doublesquare brackets to access the actual element of the list. Single square brackets will return something else:

```
> is.data.frame(l[1])
[1] FALSE
```

Tt is a named list-element and needs to be referenced by using (in my case) one of the names of the group that we split on: male or female
Below I comment the code heavily to explain what each step does.

```
> l[1]
$female                          # this is the name of the list element
     sex age income minor
1 female  20     42 FALSE
6 female  75    103 FALSE
7 female  30    148 FALSE
```

So we can access the actual element two ways:

1. by name:

   ```
   > l[1]$female
        sex age income minor
   1 female  20     42 FALSE
   6 female  75    103 FALSE
   7 female  30    148 FALSE
   ```
2. by double square brackets:

   ```
   > l[[1]]
    sex age income minor
   1 female  20     42 FALSE
   6 female  75    103 FALSE
   7 female  30    148 FALSE
   ```

That all being said, he is a working example of sorting a list (vector, holding lists) containing `data.frame`s:

```
l = split(population, population$sex)    # population is defined as shown above
N = length(l)

results <- vector("list", N)

for(i in 1:N) {

    results[[i]] <- l[[i]][order(l[[i]]$age),]
}
```

I specify the length of the vector when I create it, as we know how long the resulting list will be in advance.
... and check the results:

```
> results[[1]]
    sex age income minor
8 female  66     90 FALSE
5 female  69    131 FALSE
2 female  70     52 FALSE
9 female  95     43 FALSE

> results[[2]]
    sex age income minor
6  male  18     87 FALSE
4  male  61     97 FALSE
3  male  64    131 FALSE
7  male  72     93 FALSE
1  male  82    107 FALSE
10 male  92     42 FALSE
```

*The results depend on random choice when creating `population` at the beginning, using `sample()`.*

Comment: Sorry, for the next time i will include all the data. The main problem was that i had to use double brackets instead of one. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Final code(this works OK):

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best"){

if (outcome == "heart attack"){
  col <- 11
}else if(outcome == "heart failure"){
  col <- 17
}else if(outcome == "pneumonia"){
  col <- 23
}else{
  stop("invalid outcome")
}

data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

data <- data[, c(2, 7,col)]

colnames(data) <- c("Hospital", "State", "value")
data$value <- as.numeric(data$value)
data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
data <- split(data, data$State)


N <- length(data)
data2 <- vector("list", N)
for(i in 1:N){

  data[[i]] <- data[[i]][order(data[[i]]$value, data[[i]]$Hospital),]

  if(num =="best"){
    t <- 1;
  }else if(num == "worst"){
    t <- nrow(data[[i]])
  }else{
    t <- num
  }

  data2[[i]] <- data[[i]][t,]

}

return(data2)

}
```